# Listing the XPath to an XML node from the command line

Tags: xml, macos, bash, xpath

Given this snippet of a large deeply nested XML document (bookstore.xml), I want to know the full path to the `amazon` node. How can I print that path from the command line?

```xml
<bookstore>
<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>
    <retail>39.95</retail>
    <discounts>
      <amazon>29.99</amazon>
    </discounts>
    <currency>USD</currency>
  </price>
</book>
...
</bookstore>
```

Ideally it would look like this:

```bash
old-gregg$ magic bookstore.xml amazon
/bookstore/book/price/discounts/amazon
```

Comment: Easiest solution would probably be to write a command line program for that task in a programming language which has a library with xml support.

Comment: What do you mean by "path"? Do you want an XPath path like "bookstore/book/price/discounts/amazon"?

Comment: Good question. That was unclear. I changed the title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) and it does exactly what I'm looking for here. To install it using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```bash
$ brew update
$ brew install xmlstarlet
$ xml el bookstore.xml | grep amazon
/bookstore/book/price/discounts/amazon
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) which is a command line tool bundled with libxml2. Very likely that its available on your system.

Based on your example data (deleted the ellipsis) I played around and managed the following:

```
echo -e "du\nbye\n" | \
  xmllint --shell data
```

which returns

```
/ > du
/
bookstore
  book
    title
    price
      retail
      discounts
        amazon
      currency
/ > bye
```

This uses the interactive mode of the tool.
`du` ask to print the whole subtree starting from  current node (here root).
`bye` just exits the program.

The next step is now to parse this output.

**UPDATED:**
(assuming that the XML is in `data`)
Note that the node in question is currently hardcoded!

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "du\nbye\n" | \
  xmllint --shell data | \
  sed 's/  /: /g' | \
  awk '
    BEGIN {depth = 0}
    $NF == "amazon" {
      for(i=1; i<NF; i++) {printf("/%s", STACK[i])}
      print "/" $NF
    }
    /^\// {next}
    NF == depth + 1 {depth = NF; STACK[depth] = $NF; next}
    NF == depth {STACK[depth] = $NF; next}
    NF < depth {depth = NF; STACK[depth] = $NF; next}
    1 {print "something went horribly wrong!"}
  '
```

gives

```
/bookstore/book/price/discounts/amazon
```

To explain this look at the output after the `sed` command:

```
/ > du
/
bookstore
: book
: : title
: : price
: : : retail
: : : discounts
: : : : amazon
: : : currency
/ > bye
```

`sed` substitutes `[two spaces]` with `[:space]`.
In the following it is simple to detect the depth with `awk`.

Comment: Very nice! You're right, I already had `xmllint` installed, and I didn't realize there was a [command line mode](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html). I should have been specific that I am looking for the XPath. So: `/bookstore/book/title/price/discounts/amazon`

Comment: This looks good, thank you, but I was hoping to stay on the command line without dipping into scripting.

Comment: I absolutely understand -- Your solution is much more useful..This tool isn't installed on my machine so I did not look into it when I stumbled across its name...But I also enjoyed coding my solution:-)

Comment: I appreciate your help and I'm glad you enjoyed writing this! ✊

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 2.0 you can use `//amazon` to select the element `/ancestor-or-self::*/node-name(.)` to get the parent node names and `string-join(..., "/")` to get a path from it.

So finally the XPath 2.0 expression

```
string-join(("",//amazon/ancestor-or-self::*/node-name(.)),"/")
```

will return exactly the path you want. (although it won't add [] attribute tests, if you need them, too)

I don't know if there is any other XPath 2.0 command line tool, but I made my own a few days ago. If you happen to have fpc, you can download the [source](http://videlibri.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/videlibri/videlibri/file/86c0bce582ce/programs/internet/xidel) and compile it (there are no binaries edit: now they are there linked there: http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html). 
With it, you could just run:

```
 xidel /tmp/so2.xml --extract 'string-join(("",//amazon/ancestor-or-self::*/node-name(.)),"/")'
```

I also made a CGI service you could try:

```
  wget -qO - 'http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?extract=string-join(("",//amazon/ancestor-or-self::*/node-name(.)),"/")&data=<bookstore><book>  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>  <price>   <retail>39.95</retail>    <discounts>      <amazon>29.99</amazon>    </discounts>    <currency>USD</currency>  </price></book></bookstore>'
```